# How did the Machine correlate data over time if its memories were being erased?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

In the TV series, **Person of Interest**, Harold Finch claims that, at one point, most of the Machine's memories were erased at midnight in order to keep it from becoming too powerful.

If that's the case, how did it correlate information over time in order to identify numbers? Also, why didn't it just forget about all the training that it did with Harold, forcing him to start over training it every day?

For example, a key piece of information in figuring out that a corrupt FBI agent was planning to sell plutonium was the fact that he kept going to the same gas station (even if he didn't need gas). How would the Machine know that if its memories were being erased?

Comment: Highly related - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68533/does-the-machine-remember-already-reported-numbers

Comment: I don't remember the episode number, but there was an episode where there was a business that the workers' only job was to transcribe pages and pages of, from their view point a page of random numbers and letters, Machine's memory.  I remember the scene panning across the room full of rows of computers and people typing away while looking at the printouts.

Comment: Even more related (would be a dupe if not for, 'how does it know this happens'): [Why does the Machine remember everything?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52895/why-does-the-machine-remember-everything?rq=1)

Comment: I'm sure Harold said in that scene that relevant data was retained, and it doesn't really need to remember old numbers, it clearly has real-time access to archived data so it can look them up if they appear again (e.g. it has recordings of phone calls Harold made as a kid).

Comment: Only the machine code is reset each night, so the databases that are used for the information will exist overtime.  So it can research the history of any relationship the day it detects the threat.